# How to login into Microsoft Azure Portal and Get Auth Code?

Tags: java, azure, onedrive

What is the best way to get all the information sent by a website after sending a GET request. My main problem is i am not able to login into Microsoft Account using code.
I've wrote a code for getting all the parameters  :-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Requests {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL("Microsoft Portal URL");
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpCon.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("Response Code " + httpCon.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println("Response Status " + httpCon.getResponseMessage());
    System.out.println("Header Fields " + httpCon.getHeaderFields());
    System.out.println("Sent URL " + httpCon.getURL());
    out.close();
}
}
```

I am getting the result as follows :

```
Response Code 200 
Response Status OK 
Header Fields {null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], client-request-id=[9031e090-ea92-4581-b8d1-5b1c66076b50],
Content-Length=[7796], Expires=[-1],
Set-Cookie=[stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly,
x-ms-gateway-slice=productiona; path=/; secure; HttpOnly,
flight-uxoptin=true; path=/; secure; HttpOnly],
x-ms-gateway-service-instanceid=[ESTSFE_IN_217],
X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/8.5],
Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store], Pragma=[no-cache],
X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff],
Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains],
x-ms-request-id=[b822c62e-2aea-45b2-93c9-f1dc67576644],
Date=[Wed, 16 Mar 2016 08:41:08 GMT], P3P=[CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"],
Content-Type=[text/html; charset=utf-8]
```

I need the Redirect URI which is available only if i am logged in to Microsoft Account. So i need to log in to the website using some code.

[image: I need this code using JAVA Code]

---->>>>Thing i want to do is:
After Sending a Get request in this format :
GET "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}"

It gives me back a parameter named code(if i am using Rest Client application). For getting this code a user must be logged in into Azure Portal.

My problem is when i am doing all this with java code, i am not getting this code. The problem is i am not able to log in using java code. Help me with this issue.

Comment: What is the end result you are looking to achieve? There are easier ways of authenticating to Azure.

Comment: `I need the Redirect URI which is available only if i am logged in to Microsoft Account.` - What is this redirect URI you talk about? Can you describe your scenario in more details?

Comment: Whenever i am sending a REST request using Rest Client ,In Redirect i am getting a parameter named To and Location, where i will get a Code. I need that redirect code using java code which is only available if i am logged in.

Comment: Are you trying to invoke Azure REST APIs through Rest Client? It's not clear what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to access azure using REST.

Comment: I need a parameter named To and Location which is only available if i am logged in to website. I want to create a automated code which will log in and give me this parameter. @GauravMantri

Comment: IMHO, you're doing it wrong. Please use `Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL)` (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java) to get the authentication token in your Java App which you will then use it in your app to perform Azure Service Management/Resource Manager operations. If you look around, you will find a number of samples that will help you accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri. Link consists of lots of sample. Helped a lot but is there any other alternative?

Comment: Maybe it's time to edit the question with more info, and move the discussion to Chat? Lots of details being buried in comments here. And additional questions being asked.

Comment: Are you trying to login the Azure Portal via Azure AD Authentication with Microsoft Account? Or trying to call the Azure REST APIs listed in the [Azure Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt420159.aspx)?

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT !! Calling the Azure REST Api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Azure, there are three groups of REST APIs need to be authenticated, including Resource Management APIs, Service Management APIs and other specifical APIs like for Azure Storage or Service Bus, etc.

1. To using Resource Management APIs, you need to authenticate Azure Resource Manager requests, please see [Authenticating Azure Resource Manager requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx). And there are some samples in Java you can refer to on GitHub https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/azure-mgmt-samples.
2. To using Service Management APIs, you need to authenticate Service Management Requests, please see [Authenticating Service Management Requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx). There is an offical [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/getting-started-with-the-azure-java-management-libraries/) shown how to get started for Java.
3. To using some specifical APIs, you need to construct a `Shared Access Signature` token for delegating access. For example, [`Delegating Access with a Shared Access Signature`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee395415.aspx) for Azure Storage Service REST, you can see the [`Service SAS Examples`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn140256.aspx) to know how to construct.